# How to enable dynamic action fired in the condition of page loads in Interactive Grid?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a dynamic action which is the execution of Javascript code and enable the `Fire on Initialization` function.

However, according to the documentation:

> "Initialization has a slightly different meaning depending on how the dynamic action is defined. For dynamic actions defined to fire on interactive grid columns, this specifies if the action fires when the interactive grid row is activated for editing. For all other dynamic actions, this specifies if the action fires when the page loads."

Currently, I have to click a certain cell of the grid so that the grid row is activated for editing and the `fire on initialization` can be triggered.

Does anybody know how to enable the `fire on initialization` instantly when the page loads?

Comment: What is supposed to happen in the javascript? Is it something that can be triggered on page load? And when is your dynamic action triggered?

Comment: The condition for the trigger is `Page change[Interactive Grid]` and the Javascript is for changing the color of one cell based on the contents of the cell which I learned from this post: https://dsavenko.me/classic-report-interactive-report-interactive-grid-cell-style-based-on-data/

Comment: So your JS changes the color of specific cells on the current pages, once you switch pages in a report ? But it doesn't on the first page, which you are trying to achieve? If yes, then you can simply create a dynamic action that triggers on page load and executes the same javascript.

Comment: Thanks! It does work!

Comment: Nice. I'll make an answer out of my comment, so the questions shows up as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comments suggest, you also want to trigger the same JS, which is executed on a page switch, when the page is first loaded.

To do this, you can simply create a dynamic action, which triggers on page load, and executes the same JS code.